# Methods for Predicting Destination Locations based on Start Locations in 2D Space

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, density-estimation

I have location data $(x_1, x_2)$ and the associated labels $(y_1, y_2)$, which can be interpreted as origin and destination points in physical space. Now I would like to predict destination locations for new origin data points. Although this seems to be a straight-forward and relevant use-case, I struggle to find relevant methods for solving this problem.

What I could find is this [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10618600.2012.638219) from 2012, where the authors analyse this kind of data in the context of Spatial Point processes, and provide a conditional density estimator (section 2.2). But there adoption of an estimator from this [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1390887) for marked point process data seems arbitrary (surely mapping between two physical locations merrits a more targeted approach then for the general case for some multi-dimensional metric mark), and we get no real performance benchmarks.

I would be interested in approaches that work well in practice, but not necessarily based in the point process literature. E.g. an approach to apply standard Machine Learning algorithms here would be interesting.